# Strict type argument when calling generic function

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have this generic function definition:

```
function example<T>(...args): Partial<T> {
    ...
}
```

The question is how to force the user of this function to insert type argument when calling this function. For example:

```
example(...inputArgs);       // compilation error without using specific type.
example<User>(...inputArgs); // no compilation error when using specific type.
```

Comment: What is the type of `args`?

Comment: just multiple primitive types. multiple string values. there is no type parameter included int args.

Comment: just return type is import here. because it's type depends on the type that user provides when calling this function.

Comment: Sure, I got that. I ask because the solution requires specifying a type for `args`, otherwise a call to the function can't necessarily fail to type-check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve something like this by giving the type parameter a default, and then making the type of `args` conditional, so that when `T` is unspecified, `args` has an impossible type.

I've written `any[]` here for the type of `args` when `T` isn't `never`; you should replace this with whatever more specific type the rest parameter should have in your application.

```
function example<T = never>(...args: [T] extends [never] ? [never] : any[]): Partial<T> {
    return {};
}

// error as expected
const test: object = example();
// OK
const test2: object = example<object>();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgHgBVEBeRMZAN2QCcA+ACgDpX1aBzAZwC5EBtIgF0UqKMjAATLgMo1aIgPyzqdEX3RgAnvyEBKPgAV2sdLmL1EAbwCwAKESPEtZFBC0kVgL4Bue1-t7AHoglFpaOFpEdBk0bGRoZEl7CAQuKERxdL44ACMAKwSM8jQsPGRGPT87EMQAeQBpFLSMrKgAJhyCorJRMvwCPMLoJir7IA)

If you want the error message to be more informative, you can use this trick:

```
function example<T = never>(...args: [T] extends [never] ? [never, 'You must specify the type parameter explicitly'] : any[]): Partial<T> {
    return {};
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgHgBVEBeRMZAN2QCcA+ACgDpX1aBzAZwC5EBtIgF0UqKMjAATLgMo1aIgPyzqdADSIA5AE04IRJhBcoiLtmQQYwAJ6IoAC2R3r5xNnZZk42qLwxLULjWmiJ86GDW-EIAlHwACuyw6LjE9IgA3gCwAFCIeYi0XiC0SOkAvgDcOWU5OQD0dSi0tHA+6DJo5tDIkjkQCMZ2yMZ8cABGAFYWJuRoWHjIjNFV2Q2IAPIA0n0DJuLGAEyjk9NkovP4BONT0EzLOUA)